# Grails: Where is [domainClassName]instance defined and how is it use?

Tags: grails

I'm new in grails and trying to understand an existing code.

I focused on one module first, the name of the domain class is Employee and try to understand CRUD. I found lots of **employeeInstance?.userLastModified** of this and I was wondering how employeeInstance is defined. Is it automatic that if you create an Employee Domain class, you already have employeeInstance? How does it work and what is the question mark for?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably seen employeeInstance in a GSP or in a controller. It is defined in a controller method. You may see a controller like this:

```
class EmployeeController {

    def show(long id) {
        def employee = Employee.get(id)

        [employeeInstance: employee]
    }

}
```

And a corresponding GSP page named *grails-app/employee/show.gsp* that uses employeeInstance.

With the Groovy null-safe operator you can code this:

```
def date = employeeInstance?.userLastModified
```

instead of this:

```
def date = null
if(employeeInstance != null) date = employeeInstance?.userLastModified
```

because if employeeInstance is null, then your date variable would be set to null.

I hope you're reading the Grails documentation and coding along with it. The docs are near excellent. I got quite far in learning Grails by using the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`?` is a Groovy null-safe operator - [read here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/).

`employeeInstance` (depending on the version of Grails) should be a parameter to your controller action (`def edit(Employee employeeInstance)` for example) and is retrieved from the DB using the `id` parameter in the HTTP request.

Read [Grails user guide](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/), it is really good.